# how to replace '/' symbol to 'OF' text from fraction element of elementor carousel

Tags: loop, css, javascript

I have tried many css using :after and :before but **/** is not replaced with **OF** text.

```
<div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-fraction swiper-pagination-horizontal">
<span class="swiper-pagination-current">1</span>
" / "
<span class="swiper-pagination-total">4</span>
</div>
```